# Installing haskell-platform without pulling in an X server

Tags: apt

Is there some clever way to install `haskell-platform` from the official Debian package repositories without X support?

I need to get the Haskell compiler running on a remote server with limited free space and therefore I don't want the libxc* libraries (a simple `apt install haskell-platform` query tells me that after the operation, 988 MB of additional disk space will be used).

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind `haskell-platform` is to install the full Haskell development platform as available in Debian. There is no clever way to install a subset of that using that package.

You should install the compiler, `ghc`, and whatever extra development packages you need. See [the `haskell-platform` dependencies](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/haskell-platform) to see what’s available.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a vm locally and reconfigure and then rebuild the package to not be dependent on X - IF the original source allows this, or even not I guess depending on your coding skills.  See "[How to rebuild Debian packages](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/12/15/howto-to-rebuild-debian-packages/)".

Or you could use `alien` to convert the binary deb file to a tgz.  It wouldn't show up in a dpkg query and apt, etc wouldn't know it was installed, convert the deb file to a tgz, extract it, run ldd on the binaries and see what libs it needs, install those individually via apt or whatever, and then just move the contents of the tgz over...

Comment: The package itself is quite large so I would prefer not to rebuild it.